# Add PPA to local repository

Tags: ppa, landscape, apt-mirror

I am using apt-mirror to maintain a local repository from which my Ubuntu servers update. I need to add 2 PPA’s to my local repository. Normally in /etc/apt/mirror.list I would use this syntax:

```
deb-amd64 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
```

I am looking for the proper syntax to add PPA ‘s to my mirror.list file. Specially I am adding Landscape 18.03 and SecurityOnion PPA’s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a PPA be added to an Ubuntu repo mirror?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28124/can-a-ppa-be-added-to-an-ubuntu-repo-mirror)

Comment: I tried that example but apt-mirror returned errors about missing release files. Seems to me that the syntax after the http link needs to be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research it turns out that if you go the the Launchpad PPA web page for the desired PPA there should be a link labeled ‘Technical details about this PPA’. Clicking this link reveals the required entry for the /etc/apt/mirror.list file. It also reveals a drop down menu to select your OS version.

After selecting your OS just copy and paste the two entries into your mirror.list file and rerun apt-mirror.